# Should I use Visual C++ 2010 Express or Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate? - from Visual C++ 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, webcam, augmented-reality

I'm starting a new project that'd involve using several SDK's including:

- Intel Atom Developer SDK
- text to speech SDK (Suggestions?)
- webcam and augmented reality support of some sort (Suggestions?)

I currently have 2008, but I can also install 2010. Is there any reason to use 2010 for this project?

Comment: Prob with Atom Dev is that VS 2010 is not supported. No setup guidelines for the SDK on 2008

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2010 offers many C++0x features (auto, decltype, nullptr, lambda, rvalue, static_assert), which is a huge improvement on 2008 which only offered TR1. In addition, there's a strong native ConcRT added in VS2010 that uses all the new features as well, which makes parallel programming on the native side much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The Express editions (being free) don't allow you to run plugins/extensions whereas the paid for versions (of which Ultimate is the top option) do.

Answer (score 1):

The SVOX Text-To-Speech SDK is of very high quality. It's quite expensive though.

From what you write I don't see a reason to upgrade to VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the IDE enhancements will not much matter. What you should look at is whether there are any [new features in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx) and/or language enhancements that might be useful to you. For example, you might find the expanded support for parallel processing useful.

That would be the only reason to upgrade, IMO.

Comment: Since the OP tagged himself as Visual C++, I'm not very impressed by your .NET 4 recommendation.

Comment: @DeadMG: It was more of a consideration than a recommendation. And on what basis are you finding C++ and .NET framework enhancements mutually exclusive?

Comment: Possibly because the vast, vast, vast majority of C++ code has never heard of and doesn't care about .NET. Check the Intel Atom SDK page- it has the word "native" on it several times. The OP does not use .NET.

Comment: Compensation upvote warranted here.  The OP doesn't strike me as needing to support vast, vast, vast amounts of legacy C++ code.  Text-to-speech is particularly easy to get going with the .NET SpeechSynthesizer class.  Why an API designed to upload your product to their app store so they can take a cut of your profits  requires C or C++ code is mysterious to me.  Lack of imagination jumps to mind, this is not exactly novel.